# Bootstrap : Horizontal text alignement between columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns containing text (purple). Each column contains title (blue), content(green), and link (yellow). But, depending on column, text is more or less longer.

### Desktop view

[image: Desktop view]

However, I would like a sort of horizontal alignement for each part of my content, i.e. each title begin on the same horizontal "line", each content on the same horizontal "line" etc...
In parallel, I don't want that on mobile view, I would like text without extra vertical spaces (as horizontal alignement doesn't make sense on smartphone).

### Mobile view

[image: Mobile View]

I can't find how to solve this problem with Boostrap 3. On one hand, I can sync column (easy), but I don't know how to sync horizontal content.

### Code [[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tftn7fa9/)]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="text-justify">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non 
                </p>    

                <p>
                    <ul class="list-inline center-block text-center">
                        <li>A</li>
                        <li>B</li>
                        <li>C</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="text-justify">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non                 </p>    

                <p>
                    <ul class="list-inline center-block text-center">
                        <li>A</li>
                        <li>B</li>
                        <li>C</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>Very long long long long long long long Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="text-justify">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non                 </p>    

                <p>
                    <ul class="list-inline center-block text-center">
                        <li>A</li>
                        <li>B</li>
                        <li>C</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share html/css code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you consider using `<table>` for this?

Comment: Sure, here is a sample code on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tftn7fa9/
No, I didn't consider <table>, do you have an example ? It's surely a good idea, what about responsive design on smartphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use some js you can do it, just like this:

Here a JSFiddle example to play with: [http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/wk9esdgq/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/wk9esdgq/2/)

```js
function setHeight(objSize){
    var $window = $(window);
    var header = $('.header');
    var content = $('.wrapper-content');

    if($window.width() < 768){  /*to avoid extra vertical spaces on mobile view*/
        header.css('height', 'auto');
        content.css('height', 'auto');

        return;
    }

    if($window.width() > objSize.windowCurrentWidth){  /*resetting the max height when the window is expanding to allow the heigth decrease*/
        objSize.headerMaxHeight = 0;
        objSize.contentMaxHeight = 0;
    }

    header.each(function (index)
    {
        header.css('height', 'auto');  /*setting to auto to allow the elemelent's height change*/ 
        if($(this).outerHeight() > objSize.headerMaxHeight){ /*setting "headerMaxHeight" equal to max height of header elements*/
            objSize.headerMaxHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });

    content.each(function (index)
    {
        content.css('height', 'auto');
        if($(this).outerHeight() > objSize.contentMaxHeight){
            objSize.contentMaxHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });

    header.css('height', objSize.headerMaxHeight);  /*applying the resulting max height to the element*/
    content.css('height', objSize.contentMaxHeight);

    objSize.windowCurrentWidth = $(window).width(); /*updating the current width of the window*/
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var objSize = {
        headerMaxHeight : 0,
        contentMaxHeight : 0,
        windowCurrentWidth : $(window).width()
    }

    setHeight(objSize);

    $(window).resize(function(){
        setHeight(objSize);
    })
})
```

```css
.wrapper-content, .header, .link{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.header p{
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.content{
  background: green;
}
#content-1{
  height: 150px;
}
#content-2{
  height: 250px;
}
#content-3{
  height: 100px;
}
.link{
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 blue">
            <div class="header">
                <p>fajdklfa kajsdf lakjdfadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf as</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-content">
                <div id="content-1" class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="link"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="header">
                <p>fajdklfa kajsdf lakjdfadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asdadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf asdf as</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-content">
                <div id="content-2" class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="link"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="header">
                <p>fajdklfa kajsdf lakjdfadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asdadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf asdf as</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-content">
                <div id="content-3" class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="link"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want to use only pure css I'm afraid that you can not do it (of course not to mention that you can set fixed height to the elements), at least not both (alignment and responsive) at the same time . Because the way in html works, when you have 2 elements `a`, `b` into 2 different containers the height of `a` will not affect the height of `b`, so the elements bellow them will not be aligned, your best shot would be using flex box like this:

```css
.col-sm-4{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper{
  min-height: 415px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content-wrap, p{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
p{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.content{
  background: green;
}
#content-1{
  height: 150px;
}
#content-2{
  height: 250px;
}
#content-3{
  height: 100px;
}
.link{
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>fajdklfa kajsdf lakjdfadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf as</p>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <div id="content-1" class="content"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="link"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>fajdklfa kajsdf lakjdfadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asdadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf asdf as</p>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <div id="content-2" class="content"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="link"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>fajdklfa kajsdf lakjdfadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asdadlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf adlsfk jalfdsj lasf asd asdf asdf as</p>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <div id="content-3" class="content"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="link"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But anyway you have to set fixed height to several elements like `.wrapper`, `.link`, if you know the height, well you are lucky but keep in mind that the height of the content can change depending on resolution.

Anyway I really recommend you to use js to achieve what you want.

Comment: Really good ! Your JS solution works like a charm, thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin suggested, I would recommend using tables to accomplish your goal.  You can find more information about them at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables.  You can make them completely responsive by adding a class of table-responsive to the div that starts the table.  For example:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Purple</th>
       <th>Blue</th>
       <th>Green</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @donnaholmes. However, this solution solves only one problem : the presentation.

Comment: About responsiveness on smartphone, I did the test on smartphone using "no-more-tables". The result is : blue blue blue / green green green / yellow yellow yellow instead of blue green yellow / blue green yellow / blue green yellow. Any ideas ? https://jsfiddle.net/bushj173/